# Get Form to check if itself is already open

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have two Forms and a method in my second Form. I want that one part of the code is only executed when this second Form is not opened. What have I to write into the if-Statement to let the form check if it is open yet? I have only found solutions how to check if another form is open but not the form itself.

Comment: Where's the code you have already tried with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code :-

```
 Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
 if (IsOpened(frm2.Text))
  {
  }
```

and

```
private bool IsOpened(string name)
{
    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
    foreach (Form frm in fc)
    {
        if (frm.Text == name)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Update**:-

Linq code as suggested by  Dmitry Bychenko :-

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().Any(form => form.Text == frm2.Text))
```

Comment: I had only a constructor with public "Form2(Form1 frm1)" but now I made a second one with Form2(){InitializeComponent()}. But everytime I call the if-Statement with NOT (so check if it's not open and if true - run the code) I get false everytime and he runs nothing

Comment: Ok I've seen I had something in the wrong direction called. Now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Linq solution `if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().Any(form => form.Text == frm2.Text))`